# Extract dtypes from dataframe and map to header

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I need to return json to front end about the dataframe's column header and its datatype. I have tried:

```
return {"column header" : header, "filename" : newFilename, 
        "data": result.head(n= rowsLimit).values.tolist(), 
        "datatype": result.dtypes.tolist()}
```

On `result.dtypes.tolist()`, I am getting an `dtype('int64') is not JSON serializable` error.

Thanks

Comment: What do you expect the resulting `datatype` value to look like in JSON exactly?

Comment: Probably json array of array. [ ["Header1", "int64"], ["Header2" ,"object"] ], or just a list of datatype, frontend will map them with column header index properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Datatypes have a `name` attribute, that you can use to return strings :

```py
{"datatype": [t.name for t in result.dtypes.tolist()]}
```

Comment: Both of them are working. Thanks for introducing the name attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Converting them into strings would be an option:

```
>>> json.dumps({"datatype": [str(d) for d in result.dtypes.tolist()]})
'{"datatype": ["float64", "float64", "float64", "float64"]}'
```

Alternatively, you can use `repr`:

```
>>> json.dumps({"datatype": [repr(d) for d in result.dtypes.tolist()]})
'{"datatype": ["dtype(\'float64\')", "dtype(\'float64\')", "dtype(\'float64\')", "dtype(\'float64\')"]}'
```